# SharePoint 2013 - App. Mix CSOM and JSOM?

Tags: oauth, sharepoint-2013, csom, office365-apps, sharepoint-jsom

I need to write an Office365-App. I want to use a provider-hosted MVC-Application for this.

As I want to use some kind of "API" on some pages, that returns a JSON that then is used inside JS to display data:
Can I just mix CSOM and JSOM?

Has this any effect on the (OAuth)-Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mix CSOM and JSOM . I would suggest you could use the SharePoint Cross Domain JavaScript library (CDL) to access SharePoint data from a remotely hosted web page without the need for OAuth tokens. Please refer to below link for code sample:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint-Add-in-JSOM-CrossDomain

I have tested the codes in a CSOM OAuth authentication web application ,and it works fine .